# Selecting every 3rd item starting after the 2nd

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
$loop = 0;
$columns = 3;

<?php while ( have_posts() ) :
    the_post();
    $loop++;
?>
<li class="<?php if ( $loop % $columns == 0) echo 'last'; if ( ( $loop - 1 ) % $columns == 0 ) echo 'first'; ?>">
</li>
```

What I want to achieve is:

```
<li class="first"></li>
<li class="last"></li>
<li class="first"></li>
<li class=""></li>
<li class="last"></li>
<li class="first"></li>
<li class=""></li>
<li class="last"></li>
```

What I am getting is (which makes sense..):

```
<li class="first"></li>
<li class="=""></li>
<li class="last"></li>
<li class="first"></li>
<li class=""></li>
<li class="last"></li>
<li class="first"></li>
<li class=""></li>
<li class="last"></li>
```

meaning the first 2 are given the class first and last respectively and after that it is every 3.

If i was able to use css I would say nth-child(3n+2) but I can't because I want to assign a new class, and I can only assign a style with css.

How can I achieve it with php?

Comment: You are incrementing your loop variable before checking it's value. Move the increment to after the check/echo so you will get the next value on the next loop.

Comment: Thanks. I did that in combination with initiating the $loop variable to 2

Answer (score 1):

The following will generate the code that you gave as an example:

```
<?php
$loop = 0;
$offset = 2;

while ($loop < 100) {
    echo '<li class="';
    if ($loop < $offset) {
        if ($loop % 2 == 0) {
            echo 'first';
        } else {
            echo 'last';
        }
    } else {
        if (($loop - $offset) % 3 == 0) {
            echo 'first';
        } elseif (($loop - $offset + 2 ) % 3 == 0) { 
            echo '';
        } else {
            echo 'last';
        }
    }
    echo '"></li>';
    ++$loop;
}
```

If the `$loop` variable is under the offset it print `first` and `last` alternately otherwise it will check divisibility with 3, giving the dividend an extra offset for each condition so they will be `true` sequentially.